# PayPal subscription autorenewal enable and disable option

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

How can I implement autorenewal enable and disable option for a PayPal subscription? I have gone through their doc and couldn't find out a way to do this.

My work flow is like, user subscribes to a monthly billed plan, they then disable auto-renew and continue to have access to our service. If they don't re-enable auto-renew then the subscription will expire at the end of the billing month, and if they do re-enable auto-renew then the subscription will continue.

How can I achieve this in PayPal ...!

Answer (score 0):

An integration using [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) can disable a subscription at any time using the [suspend subscription API call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_suspend).

Comment: I don't want to disable subscription. I just want, when the user disable the auto renewal the user can use the subscription to the end of that billing cycle. If the user renews it before the end of that billing cycle, then he can continue to use the subscription in next billing cycles, if he not renew then the subscription needs to get canceled at the end of current billing cycle

Comment: That is disabling (suspending) the subscription from billing. Keeping something available until the end of the current cycle is your own application's job, not PayPal's.

Comment: Ok... for a clarification, if the subscription cycle is from 01/04/2022 - 30/04/2022 and on 15/04/2022  the user suspending the subscription and activating it again after 10 days, then it won't effect the next billing cycle right? the next billing cycle will starts from 01/05/2022 right?

Comment: anyone please help me to clarify my above doubt..!

Comment: Test in the sandbox environment